# MySQL and C Sharp dataset integration

Tags: c#, mysql

```
string table='table';
conn = new MySqlConnection(cs);
conn.Open();

MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * from @table";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@table", table);
cmd.Prepare();
//MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd); // Doesn't work.
MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * from test",conn); // WORKS.
DataSet DS = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(DS);

return DS.Tables[0]; //SQL syntax error near 'table' error at this line
```

I have a problem with the commented line, for some reason I can't get it work, What is causing this?
Thanks.

Comment: You can't make the table name from parameter.

Comment: Should I manually string replace?